# Rails: Searchform for Tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, tagging

I build a simple tagging system into my webapp (I've followed these steps: http://www.sitepoint.com/tagging-scratch-rails/)

So, now it's working fine that people can click on a Tag e.g. Dogs and they are going to "app.com/search/dogs".

But, now the people should also search for tags by using a form input field. At the moment I've tried this:

```
<%= form_tag('search', method: 'get', controller: 'static', action: 'home') do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :tag, params[:tag], placeholder: "Search Posts" %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

That brings the user to: "app.com/search/?utf8=✓&tag=Dogs&commit=Search" and that's not working. Is there a way to achieve the other logic?

Here some (maybe) interesting code samples:

**routes.rb**

```
# search by tags
get 'search/:tag', to: 'static#home', as: "search"
```

**post.rb**

```
def self.tagged_with(name)
Tag.find_by_name!(name).posts
end
```

**static_controller.rb**

```
def home
  if params[:tag]
    @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

**posts_helper.rb**

```
def tag_links(tags)
  tags.split(",").map{|tag| link_to tag.strip, search_path(tag.strip) }.join(" ")
end
```

Sorry, I'm a real beginner :) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with a note. The `form_tag` does not take `controller` or `action` parameters. Right now, they are just being printed as a form HTML tag attributes.

```
<%= form_tag('search', method: 'get', controller: 'static', action: 'home') do %>

# Generates
<form controller="static" action="search" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
```

You probably meant to do:

```
<%= form_tag('search', method: 'get') do %>
```

Now, to **back to your question**. Basically, you want to dynamically set the `action` attribute of your form. This is only possible if you use some javascript.

Add a class to your search form tag:

```
<%= form_tag('search', method: 'get', class: 'tag-search-form') do %>
```

Add this javascript code to your page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tag-search-form').submit(function(e){
    var new_action_url = $(this).attr('action') + "/" + $('#tag', this).val();
    $(this).attr('action', new_action_url)
  });
});
```

This will send user to `search/{tag-field-value}` URL. But, it would add all the parameters to it as well (`search/test?utf8=✓&tag=test&commit=Search`). If you don't want them, then you'd have to remove them in javascript before sending or alternatively setting your form's `method` attribute to `POST`.

Comment: Sorry, I see that I've tried stupid things at first! But your solution works great! thank you very much!